# Manually add reviewers to AOSP change required?

Tags: android-source, gerrit

I have pushed two changes to AOSP, same topic and they have been sitting with "Needs Code-Review Label" for 3 days now (weekend included).

I know I can assign reviewers manually, but I wouldn't know who to add. I've read around on how to [submit a patch](https://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html) but have not found if reviewers are automatically notified and the change will be processed whenever it should or if there **is something else on my side I have to do**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wait or you could, if was the case, add specific reviewers for your change. It's seens that 3 days (weekend included) aren't time enought for the review.